# How can I fix sprinklers inside concrete?

Tags: concrete, sprinkler-system

I have two sprinklers that some genius installed into concrete:

[image]

And second one:

[image]

One of them is starting to give out.  My initial thought is to:

1. Hire somebody to run new sprinkler lines.  Cut these off and leave them here dead.
2. Smash the stone to get to the sprinkler.  I tried cleaning out the area around the stone and the concrete goes real deep.  It's definitely stuck to the plastic base.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What type of pipe is used in the system?  You can likely dig down next to this and detach that head and add a new one right next to it.  It’s likely pretty simple, but you need to dig a small hole next to it to find out.

Comment: I'll take a go at that this weekend.  Will update when I have more info.

Comment: Soft mortar between brick pavers will chisel out easily. Maybe just pry up to expose soil underneath.

Comment: @JimStewart - Maybe this and a steel hammer?  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bosch-Bulldog-1-2-in-SDS-Plus-Hammer-Steel-Bull-Point-Chisel-for-Concrete-and-Masonry-Demolition-HS1415/100112971

Comment: That bit is intended to be used with a rotary hammer (drill). You want a regular cold chisel.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/TEKTON-1-2-in-Cold-Chisel-66005/205820383?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal2_rr-_-205820381-_-205820383-_-N

Comment: what does this mean?  `One of them is starting to give out`

Comment: @jsotola - It means broke. This is a 15 year old sprinkler head that needs to be replaced.

Comment: I think you’ll be able to disconnect and install a new one next to it very easily.  The new head will likely have side and bottom inlets, use the side for water and screw a “king drain” into the bottom, dig your hole 4-6” deeper than needed and put gravel in the bottom so that the king drain will allow the head to drain.  Proper drainage will increase the head life by 3 or 5 times, when water sits in the head 24/7 while it’s not in use it just eats the spring inside faster.

Comment: I dug out all the concrete with a cold chisel.  The head is not romoveable.  I guess it's somehow part of the line.  Anyway, time to dig.

Comment: The concrete at those heads looks like it is a thin layer . Should be able to chisel it away. 1st one looks like you can just unscrew the whole head from the pipe - the second you might need to make a little room to unscrew it.